# Why are my results not showing up from my database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a program that displays authors book code and book title using php and 
AJAX technology, but for some reason the data is not appearing in the table. I know my SQL code is correct as our instructor gave us the code for that, but something is preventing the data from appearing in the table. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated!

```php
<body>
        <?php
            $authorid = 0;
            $authorid = (int) $_GET['authorid'];
            if ($authorid > 0) {
                require_once('dbtest.php');
                $query = "SELECT * FROM author";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
                } else {
                echo "Title Not Returned<br>";
                }
                echo "<table border='1'><caption>Titles for </caption>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Book Code</th>";
                echo "<th>Book Title</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $q2 ="SELECT wrote.author_number As ANo, wrote.book_code As BookCd, book.book_title As Title ";
                $q2 .= " FROM wrote, book ";
                $q2 .= " WHERE wrote.book_code=book.book_code ";
                $q2 .= " AND wrote.author_number = '  ' ";
                $q2 .= " ORDER BY book.book_title";
                $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
               $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2);
                while ($row) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['BookCd']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['Title']. "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2);
                }
                echo "</table>";

            } else {
               echo "<p>No Author ID from prior page</p>"; 
            }
        ?>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: First, nothing above involves any javascript or ajax.  Second, surely `AND wrote.author_number = '  '` can't be correct.

Comment: `AND wrote.author_number = ‘  ‘` sounds very unlikely

Comment: The program does, I didn't mean the snippet contained any javascript/ajax. Your right about the AND wrote.author_number = ' ' I meant to add $authorid there

Comment: What do you mean you "forgot to add" it?  If this isn't the actual code that you're running, then it's worthless.  We need to see your _real_ code.

Comment: No actually, I have a program with 5 pages inside of it. This is the problem area although. You seem like you are mad, but I simply asked a question.

Comment: And I'm simply telling you that we can't help you if you don't give us accurate information.  If the above is not the exact code that's being run, then please replace it with the (relevant) code that is.

Comment: This is the exact code for this page TitleResults.php, usually when I add more code then this people say to add less code. I don't see how any of the other code is relevant to my issue.

Comment: Okay, so you're actually running this with `AND wrote.author_number = ' '`?  If you are, then that's your answer.  If you're not, then the above is _not_ your exact code.  One of those is the case.  I'm just tryin to determine which.

Comment: Yes, I am running it with AND wrote.author_number = ' '. I said I meant to change that prior to asking a question on stack overflow, but did not.

Comment: Okay, so then this is simply a typo problem, yes?  It works when you actually put a value there?

Comment: No, I still get no results in my table. When I run the program none of the data from the database appears in my table.

Answer (score 0):

The suspicious line is: AND wrote.author_number = '  '
Why is it empty?

Put a check after the second query:

```
$r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r2) > 0) {
    echo "rows are Returned<br>";
} else {
    echo "rows are Not Returned<br>";
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2);
```